# MySQL Insert to NULL INT Column with PHP sprintf

Tags: php, mysql, string-formatting, printf

I'm trying to format a mysql insert statement using php `sprintf` but doing so inserts a `0` rather than `NULL` into the record column. I'm looking for a way around this while still using `sprintf` for formatting:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `efix_lines`
                     (EventID, Serial, SerialRequired, PartNumber,
                      MfgRev, DefectID, CircuitReference, CreatorID,
                      CreatorName, Created)
                   VALUES (%d, '%s', %d, '%s', '%s', %d, '%s', %d, '%s', '%s')",
                      $oSubmitData['EventID'],
                      EVL($oSubmitData['Serial'], NULL),
                      EVL($oSubmitData['SerialRequired'], NULL),
                      EVL($oSubmitData['PartNumber'], NULL),
                      EVL($oSubmitData['MfgRev'], NULL),
                      EVL($oSubmitData['DefectID'], NULL),
                      EVL($oSubmitData['CircuitReference'], NULL),
                      $oSubmitData['CreatorID'],
                      $oSubmitData['CreatorName'],
                      $pDate );

//I made this quick EVL function to help with shorthand ternary operators within my actual syntax
function EVL( $var1, $var2 ){
   return ( empty( $var1 ) ? $var2 : $var1 );
};
```

The problem is occurring on `DefectID` column when attempting to insert `NULL` since it is empty.  `sprintf` wants to insert an integer as `%d` dictates, so it inserts `0` rather than `NULL`.  What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use `%s`, the reason being, that for PHP `null` is not a valid value for an integer, while for MySQL it perfectly is (assuming the column is not declared `NOT NULL`).

You might want to do something like

```
function NVLint($var) {
  if (empty($var)) return 'NULL';
  else if (!is_numeric(!$var)) return 'NULL';
  else return round($var);
}
```

and

```
... sprintf ...
  NVLint($oSubmitData['DefectID']),
```

Comment: absolutely great! I just ended up using `%s` then passing `'NULL'` from my EVL() function, your function seems valid too though!